# Sequences that satisfy patterns up to a certain point

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

I am a High School teacher and a question came up recently from one of my students. (Mind they haven't seen any Calculus yet so I am a bit constrained regarding what I can explain to them).

We are studying sequences and a girl asked me if could there be a sequence $a_{n}$ such as, for example, begins regular like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... and, say, at $a_{200} = 4$ instead of 200. Honestly, I didn't know. So, I dove into the subject and I found how to produce such sequence, but, the thing is that $a_{201}$ won't be necessarily 201 after the jump. The pattern won't be present again. I can live with it, and so does she, I guess.

Anyway, it all sparked my own curiosity and I think I came up with a sequence that has an infinite trail of zeroes starting at $a_3$ that might be useful. I would like to see if it is correct. Thanks a lot to all of you.

$$\left \{ n+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left [(-1)^k \frac{2k+1}{(k-1)!}\prod_{i=1}^{k+1}(n-i)  \right ]\right \}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE..Nice question,for first time here..;)

Comment: You can create any sequence you want. Is $a_{200}$ the only element that's not of the $a_n=n$ form?

Comment: @Andrei Yes, exactly. I want to know if there is a non-recursive form of the general term for such sequence that doesn't either resort to splitting like "if n doesn't equal 200 do this, and if it does, do that"

Comment: And also, I would like to know if the formula I posted is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a peaked function at $200$, with a maximum of $1$, such as a gaussian or $\exp(-|n-200|)$, and take the floor of it. Multiply it by $200$ and subtract it, to get $$a_n=n-200\lfloor e^{-|n-200|}\rfloor$$

Alternative solution, say you want only the first 199 terms to be $n$, then you can always add a polynomial with roots $1,2,...,199$, like your last product.

Alternative solution, start from something like $$200\arctan\left(\tan\frac n{200}\right)$$